# Jquery changing image source dynamiccaly

Tags: jquery, css, properties

I made a menu of icons, now I want to change an images source based on the icon clicked.

```
   $(".iconchangers").click(function(){

  var newicon = $(this).attr('src');
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.changetheicon').css("src",newicon);   




  })


   })
```

When I alert newicon, everything works. So the error lies in the changing of the source. Yet I don't know why it's not working.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/co6v92aqrutnt5b/Screenshot%202014-02-02%2023.53.55.png
http://jsfiddle.net/h2tFw/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`src` is not really a style, so `css()` won't help you, and in this case it's not the attribute you want either, but the elements `src` property

```
$(".iconchangers").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr')
           .find('.changetheicon')
           .prop("src", this.src);
});
```

Of course there's no way to tell if you're targeting the right elements, as you didn't post any markup ?

Comment: If this is a simple icon, to improve your user's experience, you should explore using `background-position` css rules with a `background-image` sprite image. You change the visible icon by repositioning the image position. See [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) for a full explanation.

This will mean your icon changes instantly without having to load a new image.

Comment: I added a fiddle. I need to change the image source for each tr on the page, then save every image source in an array to LocalStorage because I'll need them on another page. I can't get it to work btw :w

Comment: I didn't use the right selector indeed. Shudve been: $(this).closest('tr[id*="tr_group"]').find('.changetheicon') :) Thans alot mate!